# Problem detaching listener from Firestore nested / sub-collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

My scenario is a chat app with the following setup in Firestore

```
channels (collection)
  id (doc)
    messages (collection)
    {channelObj}
  id (doc)
    messages (collection)
    {channelObj}
etc
```

I've successfully attached a listener to the sub collection messages although I am having trouble detaching that listener, so when I switch from and to chat channels I get duplicate entries as the listeners keep stacking.

Here's the script block from my vue file

```
<script>
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import SingleMessage from './SingleMessage'
import MessageForm from './MessageForm'

export default {
  name: 'messages',
  components: {
    SingleMessage,
    MessageForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      channelsRef: firebase.firestore().collection('channels'),
      messages: [],
      channel: '',
      unsubscribe: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['currentChannel']),
  },
  watch: {
    currentChannel: async function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.messages = []
      oldValue && 
        await this.detachListeners(newValue, oldValue)
      await this.unsubscribe
      await this.timeout(2000)
      await this.addListeners(newValue)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addListeners(newValue) {
      this.channelsRef
        .doc(newValue.id)
        .collection('messages')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            if (change.type == 'added') {
              let doc = change.doc
              this.messages.push({
                id: doc.id,
                content: doc.data().content,
                timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,
                user: doc.data().user,
              })
            }
          })
        })
      //
      console.log('[addListeners] channel:', newValue.id)
    },
    detachListeners(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.unsubscribe = 
      this.channelsRef
        .doc(oldValue.id)
        .collection('messages')
        .onSnapshot(() => {})
      //
      console.log('[detachListeners] channel:', oldValue.id)
    },
    timeout(ms) {
      console.log('waiting...')
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

As you can see I am using a Vue watcher to monitor when the channel changes. To clarify, the `console.log` are firing with the correct doc ids so it should be targeting correctly. I tried using asynchronous code to await the detach but that does not work.

The docs advising saving the detach code to a variable and calling that, which I am now doing in my watch block. When console logging that it says this

```
ƒ () {
            asyncObserver.mute();
            firestoreClient.unlisten(internalListener);
        }
```

So I am a bit lost here, seems I am targeting the right collection with the right method for unlistening ... any other steps I can take to debug?

Comment: Maybe this is a typo, but in your `watch` object you are missing the parentheses to actually perform the `unsubscribe` method: `await this.unsubscribe` instead of `await this.unsubscribe()`.

Comment: I think it's correct, the Firebase docs call for saving the detach function to a variable (which I save as `unsubscribe` in `data()`) and then I am calling it as a variable in `await this.unsubscribe`. A little convoluted but I believe it's the Vue way of doing things. In any case, the desired code runs when called in `await this.unsubscribe`. I think this question is more a Firebase problem than js

Comment: I agree that you are storing the reference to the unsubscribe function, but in my opinion you are not invoking this function. Either way, wish you good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store in `data` the function returned by the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) method and call this function in order to detach the listener.

In your existing code you are indeed declaring an `unsubscribe` object in `data` but you are not correctly assigning to it the function returned by the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) method (you should do that in the `addListeners()` method) and you are not calling it correctly (you do `this.unsubscribe` instead of `this.unsubscribe()`).

I've not reproduced your full case, since it implies a Vuex store and some extra components but you will find below a similar code that demonstrates how it works (my settings are a bit different than yours -I use `require("../firebaseConfig.js");` and `fb.db.collection(channel)`- but you'll easily get the philosophy!):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="currentChannel" placeholder="Enter Current Channel">
    <p>CurrentChannel is: {{ currentChannel }}</p>
    <div class="messagesList">
      <li v-for="m in messages">{{ m.name }}</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const fb = require("../firebaseConfig.js");
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [],
      currentChannel: null,
      listener: null    //We store the "listener function" in the object returned by the data function
    };
  },
  watch: {
    currentChannel: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.messages = [];
      if (this.listener) {
        this.listener();  //Here we call the "listener function" -> it detaches the current listener
        this.addListeners(newValue);
      } else {
        this.addListeners(newValue);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addListeners(channel) {
      this.listener = fb.db.collection(channel).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          if (change.type == "added") {
            let doc = change.doc;
            this.messages.push({
              id: doc.id,
              name: doc.data().name
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.messagesList {
  margin-top: 28px;
}
</style>
```

---

So, if we try to apply this approach to your code, the modified code would be as follows:

```
<script>
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import SingleMessage from './SingleMessage'
import MessageForm from './MessageForm'

export default {
  name: 'messages',
  components: {
    SingleMessage,
    MessageForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      channelsRef: firebase.firestore().collection('channels'),
      messages: [],
      channel: '',
      unsubscribe: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['currentChannel']),
  },
  watch: {
    currentChannel: function(newValue, oldValue) {
          this.messages = [];
          if (this.unsubscribe) {
            this.unsubscribe(); 
            this.addListeners(newValue);
          } else {
            this.addListeners(newValue);
          }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addListeners(newValue) {
      this.unsubscribe = this.channelsRef
        .doc(newValue.id)
        .collection('messages')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            if (change.type == 'added') {
              let doc = change.doc
              this.messages.push({
                id: doc.id,
                content: doc.data().content,
                timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,
                user: doc.data().user,
              });
            }
          });
        });
      console.log('[addListeners] channel:', newValue.id)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```