# How to detach firestore listener in Redux Action

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am using Redux+Firestore to grab data and populate my store. I'm using `.onSnapshot` to listen to data in a given collection. What I'm not able to do is detach the listener once I am finished.

I've read the Firestore docs and understand that in order to detach the listener you need to store the callback (`.onSnapshot`) as a variable, and then call that variable to detach.

The issue I'm facing with this is that I'm using Redux (and attaching/detaching in `componentDidMount/componentWillUnmount` respectively).

I've seen a pattern used [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682344/problem-detaching-listener-from-firestore-nested-sub-collection?rq=1) (albeit in Vue) where the callback is stored in a local data variable, so I tried dispatching the callback itself to the Redux store but it doesn't receive it.

Code below:

NOTE: I've tried adding true/false bool's as parameters in `getRoomActivity` to call `unlisten()` based on the link shared above, at this point - I'm at a loss.

```
// group.js (redux action file)
export const getRoomActivity = (roomId) => (dispatch) => {
  const unlisten = roomCollection
    .where('room', '==', roomId)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const roomItems = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        roomItems.push(doc.data());
    });
  dispatch({ type: GET_ROOM_ACTIVITY, payload: roomItems });
  });
};

//Room.js (component)
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getRoomActivity(this.props.roomId);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.getRoomActivity(this.props.roomId);
  }
```

Comment: Why do you use `await` when you declare the listener?  `onSnapshot()` does not return a Promise but a function, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#on-snapshot. I don't know Redux but it is this function returned by the `onSnapshot()` method that you have to call when you want to detach the listener. As you have seen in the answer you refer to, in Vue.js we store this function in a variable and call it when necessary. We would do the same in "pure" JavaScript, I guess that you should be able to do the same in Redux.

Comment: Re: async - didn't properly understand `onSnapshot()`. I am attempting to call `unlisten` in `componentWillUnmount` however I think it isn't calling the function on the same listener, as any change to the collection in question is being listened to (according to console.log)

Comment: Can't you do something like: `const unlisten = roomCollection
    .where('room', '==', roomId)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {...});
  componentWillUnmount(){
        this.unlisten();
  }`?. Again, I am not at all versed in Redux but just giving a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a thunk with `dispatch()`, the value returned by the thunk is passed up the chain.

e.g.

```
function delayedHello(dispatch) {
  setTimeout(() => dispatch({type:'delayed-hello', payload:'hello'}), 1000);
  return '1s';
}

let val = dispatch(delayedHello);
console.log(val) // logs '1s'
```

So we can apply this same trait to the thunk you return from `getRoomActivity(someRoom)` so that the `onSnapshot`'s unsubscribe function is passed back to the caller.

```js
// group.js (redux action file)
export const getRoomActivity = (roomId) => (dispatch) => {
  return roomCollection // CHANGED: Returned the unsubscribe function
    .where('room', '==', roomId)
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const roomItems = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          roomItems.push(doc.data());
      });
      dispatch({ type: GET_ROOM_ACTIVITY, payload: roomItems });
    });
};

//Room.js (component)
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = dispatch(this.props.getRoomActivity(this.props.roomId));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```