# Unsubscribe to firestore(...).onSnapshot() does not work when dispatch() is involved

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-firebase

Main goal: unsubscribe correctly all firestore-listeners before logging out the user, preventing leaks.

*Libraries involved:  react, react-native, redux, redux-thunk and react-native-firebase.*

Problem: **Unsubscribe to firestore(...).onSnapshot() does not work when dispatch() is involved.**

I fetch data with onSnapshot and returns the unsubscribe function to the caller component which I call on user logout. Strangely, UNSUBSCRIBE only works when no dispath is made...

I have a component (component.js) that is connected to redux store and fetch constantly some user data like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.unsubscribe = this.props.userFetch(); // userFetch is an action creator in actions.js
}
```

In actions.js

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const userFetch = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore()
      .doc(`users/${auth().currentUser.uid}`)
      .onSnapshot({
        error: e => console.warn('ERROR IN FETCH: ', e),
        next: SnapshotUser => {
          console.log('User: ', SnapshotUser.data());
          // Will dispatch action below
        },
      });
    return unsubscribe;
  };
};
```

Note that there is no DISPATCH for the moment in the previous action creator.

If I call unsubscribe in component.js, the firestore onSnapshot listener gets unsubscribed correctly, like this:

```js
onLogoutPressed = () => {
  this.unsubscribe(); // <-- HERE it works (for the moment...)
  auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('user has been signout');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error: ',error);
    });
};
```

Now if I want to send my fetched data to the redux store with a dispatch, I add the dispatch like this in actions.js

```
export const userFetch = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore()
      .doc(`users/${auth().currentUser.uid}`)
      .onSnapshot({
        error: e => console.warn('ERROR IN FETCH: ', e),
        next: SnapshotUser => {
          console.log('User: ', SnapshotUser.data());
          // Will dispatch action below
          dispatch({   // <--------------------------------- HERE
            type: 'USER_FETCH_SUCCESS',
            payload: SnapshotUser.data(),
          });
        },
      });
    return unsubscribe;
  };
};
```

But then suddenly in my component.js, the this.unsubscribe doesn't work anymore on logout.

I've found that guy doing the same but works for him on React: [here](https://brandonlehr.com/reactjs/2018/11/08/unsubscribing-from-firestore-realtime-updates-in-react).
The solution provided by this other guy is basically the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952371/how-to-detach-firestore-listener-in-redux-action) too.

It looks like the firestore-onsnapshot-listener is wrapped in some dispatch call due to redux-thunk and I cant understand how it behaves now.

Does someone has any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it with the help of @ioss on Reactiflux.
The componentDidMount was mounted twice for some weird reasons, creating multiple listeners thus unmounting one was not enough.
Solved it by adding another run on unsubscribe() in componentWillUnmount().